# Set the nil value for session_id while session timeout - devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

In rails 3.2.13 project, I am using devise(1.4.2) plugin for authentication system. Here, I need to update current_user's session_id to nil value after session timeout. How to override the timeout function?

After sign in, session_id field will update like "A9nEDMZFl7D4ytSfWxrY". After sign out, session_id field will update with nil value. Now I need to update the same nil value for session expiry. How to modify session expiry function?

In session's create action, I am updating session_id using Devise.friendly_token

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set session to nil. You should do `reset_session`, to reset the session id.

Now, those two cases you mention are already handled by devise:

- upon session creation, devise does a `reset_session` to block session fixation
- when your session is expired, it does not really matter what happens with your session: you will 
  redirected to login, and after login your session will be reset again

If you are storing your sessions in a table, as you should, you could do even better and just remove expired sessions from the database. If you are using redis as session store, you can auto-expire your sessions and it will handle that for you.

Mind you: that is just nice to have, since an expired session will not be allowed in by devise anyway.

One last remark: why are you still using version 1.4.2?